# Quickly (un)comment blocks of code in Rust

Tags: rust, comments

In languages such as Java, I often use the following pattern for quickly commenting/uncommenting whole blocks of code:

```java
/* *
hello.world();
/* */

// I just have to add one '/' and the block is uncommented:

/* */
hello.world();
/* */
```

However, in Rust, the above code creates a syntax error, as it is not allowed to have unequal numbers of `/*` and `*/` in a Rust file.

But is there a similar way for quickly commenting/uncommenting blocks in Rust that does not involve using editor macro-commands?

Comment: Although you say without editor commands, I recommend using an editor like VSCode where `Ctrl+/` can comment/uncomment entire blocks of code.

Comment: You know the two ways to comment out code. Use one of them, because there's no other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use single-line comments to activate/deactivate your multi-lines comment, e.g.

```
/*
commented_out();
// */

//*
not_commented();
// */
```